# Topology surfaces clarification

Tags: general-topology

I am not a math student, but while studying robotics I came across $\mathbb R^2 \times (S^1)^2$. Please help me Understanding this . I know $\mathbb R^2$ is a plane and $S^1$ is a circle.

Comment: Provide us with a little context so we can better help you

Comment: This is a 4D object so it's not easy to visualise. $(S^1)^2$ is a torus, so you may try to think of it as a torus in which every point is actually a plane.

Comment: There's no question here and as such it is not appropriate for this site. You should edit it to include some specific question, otherwise it should be removed.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop  The question is how to explain that space.  As a start could you explain why S$^2$ is a torus instead of a sphere.  It is an appropriate question as witnessed by two sensible replies one of which was helpful to  the person who asked the question.  Would that all replies be like that, but alas, too many are not.

Comment: Torus on wikipedia explains why it is $S^1\times S^1$. $S^2$ is *not* $(S^1)^2$ unfortunately -- you have to be careful with notation.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thanks for understanding it is indeed a question and support

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for explanation. after some study am partially okay with the meaning . sorry for delayed response

Comment: @paulblartmathcop You seem to be rude without observing the question carefully. Your points(3.5k) mean nothing . You may well go ahead and remove the post. THE QUESTION WAS, TRY TO EXPLAIN THE "SPACE" IN LAYMAN TERMS. Please observe, think and answer . For somebody who hopes to get some explanation its really discouraging.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop to my understanding here is the answer . $R^{2} \times (S^{1})^2$ = $R^{2} \times S^{1} \times S^{1}$ = $R^{2} \times T^{2}$. A robot translating and oriented in torus. (I am not a math student and I hope it is right)